Would comments in ReactJS show in client browsers with Vite?
Currently, I am using Vite with ReactJS and have the following two types of comments inside my codes, for example:
export const Main = () => {

  useEffect(() => {
    // console.log("first type of comment.");
  }, [])
  
  return (
    <>
      {/* <div>Second type of comment.</div> */}
    </>
  );
}

Will these two types of comments be visible in client browsers, if I use vite and vite build, respectively?
For similar issues, How comment a JSP expression? talks about whether the comments will be visible in client browsers, but it is for JSP type of comments.

Did you check​?

@Ry- Yes, I read Preserve comments in Vite and Removing All Comments, Including Legal Ones on Vite Build.

But not sure which one is right, and the documentation is a bit vague on the Build For Production.

I mean: did you run the build and check if the comments were in the output?

@Ry- I could not find any comments in the output; the sources seem masked.

It depends on build process. When you run a prod build - vite build, it initiates a minification process and strips of both style of comments

JS //javascript comment, and
JSX  {/* <div>JSX comment</div> */} 
So, rest assured, when you run vite build, both types of comments will be removed, and they won't be visible to the users in their browsers.


You can configure esbuild in vite to remove things like 'console', 'debugger' before putting it into production, here if you want to remove comment lines (including JavaScript comments and JSX comments) you can add terser plugin to vite config to remove that when building.
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';

export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
    return {
        build: {
            rollupOptions: {
                plugins: [
                    terser({
                        output: {
                            comments: false,
                        },
                    }),
                ],
            },
        },
    };
});

